# Filter one way binding - inline filter

Tags: angularjs, filter

So I have this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control">
```

And

```
<tr ng-repeat="city in cities | filter: search">
      <td>{{city.description}}</td>
      <td>{{(countries | filter : {id:city.idCountry}:true)[0].description}}</td>
</tr>
```

I have a table and I use the syntax above to display a property (description) which is in a different array of objects (countries), because they have a foreign key relation in the DB. I want to be able to filter by this property (description in countries) existent in this foreign object. I don't know how to accomplish this.

So far I can only filter by properties that are inside the city object.

Example:

```
city = {
     id: 55,
     code: "C4589",
     description: "NYC",
     idCountry: 35
}

country = {
      id: 15,
      description: "US"
}
```

The generated HTML is

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchF" class="form-control">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="ng-binding">Dallas</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">C458</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">US</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ng-binding">NYC</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">N4596</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">US</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: give us an example of an `item`. How does an object of an `item` look like?

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi done. I added an example of both objects

Comment: I don't really understand the relation between the two objects. `IDUser` is a foreign key in the `account` table, meanwhile `IDAccount` is a foreign key in the `item` table? This is a very strange design. Also, both of your objects contain the `name` field, should that be the same? I would probably suggest avoiding angular filters and doing all the login inside the controller.

Comment: Can you show us example of `items`, `accounts` and desired output, i.e html?

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi There isn't a table called "item", but there are several tables with this type of relationship. I am using a relational DB so I am storing the ID. ignore the IDUSer, it's just a field to determine who was the last user who modified the record. Also, the name field is just a description of a record. An example of a table with this relationship is Country and Cities. Where a city has an IDCountry. Both country and city have a description field. What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to search by the country description from the city CRUD.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov I added an example